# Login to SQL causes ORA-12560 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

Couple of days ago I have created new database on Virtual machine. After cloning it (Also IP address has been changed), I am unable to connect to the database using SQL Plus. What interesting is, I can work with this database when using

```
C:\Users\Administrator>set ORACLE_SID=clm

C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 10 00:36:11 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYSDBA AS SYSDBA
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

It is the same when I use following statemanet:
`C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus sysdba/clm@//localhost:1521/clm`

Here is my **C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora** file:

```
    SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

    NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT) ? ADR_BASE = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

And output from **lsnrctl services**

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl services

 LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-JAN-2014 00:45
 :24

 Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
 Services Summary...
 Service "clm" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "clm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1036 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
 Service "clmXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "clm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: WIN-E5E1BKVLT79, pid: 988>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN-E5E1BKVLT79)(PORT=62941))
 Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:85 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
 Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: WIN-E5E1BKVLT79, pid: 2484>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN-E5E1BKVLT79)(PORT=49201))
 The command completed successfully
```

How further I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Have you changed the IP address in the `listener.ora` after cloning; you've removed the HOST value now, but is WIN-E5E1BKVLT79 the old or cloned host name, and does it resolve to the IP you're expecting? Are all DB-related services started, and is there anything in the Db or listener alert logs?

Comment: What I have noticed, I had only listener.ora.old file. I have replaced it to listener.ora and changed ip address and restarted it the service, I got weird error in lsnrctl:
`
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oraclm(PORT = 1521)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 1004: Unknown error
`

It disappears when I rename back listener.ora file.

Comment: WIN-E5E1BKVLT79 is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file.

How can I check DB-related services started, and is there anything in the Db or listener alert logs? Which command or logs you would advice me?

Answer (score 0):

A) Check your password file in the %ORACLE_HOME%/dbs/
B) Edit your tnsnames.ora for remote connections
C) If it's a windows host, as it looks like you have to create a windows service using oradim:
   ie:

```
oradim -startup -sid %your_oracle_sid% –usrpwd %your_password% -starttype SRVC,INST -pfile %pfile_location%
```